# XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'url'. Origin 'url' is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am getting this error while using this code.

```
function like (id){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../web/like/" + id + "/",
                success: function(response) {
                    // succeed silently
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    // fail silently
                },
            });
}
```

Now i have looked at a whole bunch of questions with the same error code but this is submitting the ajax request on the same domain whereas all the ones i have seen are from other sources.

Exact error message,
XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL/web/like/3/. Origin URL is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Why not use an absolute path?

Comment: How can a relative path result in different domain, port, scheme or origin altogether? You are probably misrepresenting this. Add the *exact* error message.

Comment: Yeah but it's not exact.

Comment: Could it be that the credentials used to make the request do not have access to that location, causing your access control to return that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put that on the page which you call :

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```